# Nginx Error 502 when uploading large images

Tags: nginx, php, memory, 502

The environment:

- Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on a 256MB VPS
- LEMP stack with PHP 7.1
- Latest WordPress install with Avada theme & associated plugins only.
- At least 75MB of RAM free when not uploading

The error:

- Getting 502 errors when uploading large images ~8MB and 24MP. The server receives the file okay, but returns the error when processing thumbnails.
- I used this server to explore possible self-hosting image solutions, so I also installed Lychee temporarily, and the same situation occurs when uploading images.

Nginx Log:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
```

PHP7.1-FPM Log:

```
[pool www] child 451 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL)
```

Nginx Config: https://pastebin.com/MtWdeeGz

Nginx Site Config: https://pastebin.com/YqWg9Euy

PHP.ini - pastebin.com/cJpgchQj

Things I've tried but no avail:

- Used sockets instead of TCP
- Implemented fast_cgi params in both the nginx.conf and the site config
- Increased WordPress memory limit in wpconfig.php
- Increased PHP memory limit in PHP.ini
- Increased execution time

Thanks for any help and insight that you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information in question, but I think your php-fpm process killed by OOM-killer during thumbnail processing. You could check it by command `dmesg | grep kill`. There is two way to solve this issue, increase RAM or add swap, see instruction [there](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: Thanks! OOM was killing my PHP processes. My provider won't permit addition of swap, so I guess I'll have to find a different path.